# How to determine a direction of Coriolis force at southern hemisphere

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, coriolis-effect

If I take my rotating coordinate system as it's shown in the below picture :
[image]

Why does using $F=-2mw\frac{\mathrm{d}r}{\mathrm{d}t}$ for a free fall of a particle in the southern hemisphere give me the wrong answer? I know that I can calculate the direction of force by cross product in the northern hemisphere, then reverse it to determine the direction in the southern hemisphere. However, where I'm making a mistake is that I am unable to determine this direction in southern hemisphere directly.

Because for example, for an angle in the range of $[\frac{3\pi}{2} , 2\pi]$ the $\hat{j}$  direction of $\Omega$ is positive and the cross product gives the direction of Coriolis force $+\hat{i}$.

**Where am I making a mistake?**

Comment: In the northern hemisphere the Coriolis force on a falling object points to east. Why do you think the force should point to west in the southern hemisphere?

Comment: Because direction of swirling is opposite in northern and southern hemisphere.

Comment: Swirling (horizontal movement) is different from falling (vertical movement). You need to calculate $\vec{\omega}\times\vec{v}$ and look at the results.

Comment: watch this , water moves in radial direction means -k hat  :  https://slate.com/technology/2015/06/coriolis-effect-proving-it-does-work-differently-in-different-hemispheres.html